# How to select a path in a find [...] -exec cp {} dest_dir \; command?

Tags: find, cp

I'm having a hard time trying to limit the path with `find`.

I have this command `find ${DIR_PATH} -type f -name ".py" -exec cp --parent {} ${DEST_DIR} \;`

Which give me this output :

```
${DIR_PATH}/a/main.py
${DIR_PATH}/a/b/resources.py
${DIR_PATH}/c/__init__.py
${DIR_PATH}/c/main.py
```

I definitely know `${DIR_PATH}` as I am looking in this directory. How can I get :

```
a/main.py
a/b/resources.py
c/__init__.py
c/main.py
```

The objective is to get the following in the destination directory :

```
${DEST_DIR}/a/main.py
${DEST_DIR}/a/b/resources.py
${DEST_DIR}/c/__init__.py
${DEST_DIR}/c/main.py
```

But I have this instead :

```
${DEST_DIR}/${DIR_PATH}/a/main.py
${DEST_DIR}/${DIR_PATH}/a/b/resources.py
${DEST_DIR}/${DIR_PATH}/c/__init__.py
${DEST_DIR}/${DIR_PATH}/c/main.py
```

Note : `DIR_PATH` and `DEST_DIR` are set up at the beginning of a sh file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `${DEST_DIR}` is an absolute path, one way could be to `cd` to `${DIR_PATH}` before running `find` on the current directory. This way, the paths from `find` will all be relative:

```
cd "${DIR_PATH}"
find . -type f -name ".py" -exec cp --parent {} "${DEST_DIR}" \;
```

(If `DEST_DIR` isn't an absolute path, prefix it with `$PWD` from before the `cd`.)

You could instead use `rsync`. [Something like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32527277/2072269):

```
rsync -a --prune-empty-dirs --include "*/"  --include="*.py" --exclude="*"  "${DIR_PATH}/" "${DEST_DIR}"
```

(Note the trailing slash after `${DIR_PATH}`)

Comment: Thank you muru !
This works perfectly, I prefer not to use rsync as I use it later. Otherwise it will be confusing for me.

Comment: Note that if you change a `find` command to something like `find . -type f -name ".py" -exec cp --parent -t "${DEST_DIR}" {} \+` it won't execute separate `cp` for each and every file which might significantly speed the execution.